# optimize solution for multi user type , two of them share manytomany field

Tags: django, django-models, database-design, many-to-many, query-optimization

The system is mutli user(based on signals) :

- Company
- Driver
- Client

  - Company and Driver have team and can invite drivers to their teams
  - So company and driver share the team field which is many to many field
- I found two solutions :

  - First one:

    - Team field will be in the BaseUser mode.
    - pros:

      - Simple implementation
    - Cons:

      - client user will have a team field on it’s record in database which mean redundant data.
  - Second one:

    - Create abstract model hold team field, then both company, driver models will inherit that abstract model.
    - Pros:

      - Avoid creating team field in Client user
    - Cons:

      - More code
      - Code a little bit messy
      - Increase complexity of invitation and join logic ( must be optimized to fetch if the invitation creator is a company or driver then deal depend on that) , (in first solution the creator always will be the BaseUser)
      - Add an extra fields to invitation object refere to CompanyMembership and DriverMembership, (in first solution was just a field refere to the general membership), but this invitation object will delete after joining , will be kept in database in case the invited one does not joined , and can solve by using celery to delete expired invitations.

## is there another better solution and if not which one of both is better ?

**The second solution implementation:**

Abstract models that hold the common fields:

```
class CommonFields(models.Model):
    team = models.ManyToManyField(
        "driver.DriverProfile", symmetrical=False, blank=True, through="Membership")
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        "users.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="driver_profile")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class BaseMembership(models.Model):
    class MemberType(models.TextChoices):
        FAMILY = "FAMILY", _("Family")
        TAXI_DRIVER = "TAXI DRIVER", _("Taxi Driver")

    member = models.ForeignKey(
        "driver.DriverProfile", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    member_type = models.CharField(
        _("Type"), max_length=50, choices=MemberType.choices, default=MemberType.TAXI_DRIVER
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        default_related_name = 'team_members'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Only allow this relationship to be created if
        if self.leader != self.member:
            super(BaseMembership, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Company Membership:

```
# Company Memebership  ===========================================================================
class Membership(BaseMembership):
    leader = models.ForeignKey(
        CompanyProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='owner')

    class Meta:
        default_related_name = 'company_members'
```

Driver Membership

```
# Driver Membership ================================================================================
class Membership(BaseMembership):

    leader = models.ForeignKey(
        DriverProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='owner')
```

Invitation and joining view(I have not update it yet to deal with the second solution):

class InvitationView(viewsets.ViewSet):
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

```
@action(["post"], detail=False)
def invite(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = InvitationSerializer(
        data=request.data, context={"request": request})
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    invitation = serializer.save()
    uid = invitation.uid
    data = {"uid": uid}
    return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

@action(["post"], detail=False)
def join(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = JoinSerializer(
        data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    uid = serializer.uid
    try:
        invitation = Invitation.objects.get(uid=uid)
    except (Invitation.DoesNotExist):
        return Response(
            "invalid invitation code", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        )
    membership = invitation.membership
    invitation.delete()
    driver = request.user.driver_profile
    if driver != membership.leader:
        membership.driver = driver
        membership.save()
        return Response("joined successfully", status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        membership.delete()
        return Response("leader can't join as a driver to his team", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Can a Driver belong to more than one Team? Can a Team serve more than one Company? Other similar relationship questions come up. Your best bet here is to use [entity-relationship data modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) (E-R) to work out what you need for your application, then implement it. Django modeling maps fairly well to abstract E-R models.

Comment: thank you for replying,
yes driver can belong to more than one team , but team can server one company, i will generate multi teams by creating proxy models using type field

Answer (score 0):

I would setup my tables like that:

**Company**
companyid, PK
companyname, NN

**Team**
teamid, PK
teamname, NN

**Company-Team**
companyid, FK, Company.companyid, NN
teamid, FK, Team.teamid, NN

**Driver**
driverid, PK
drivername, NN

**Driver-Team**
driverid, FK, Driver.driverid, NN
teamid, FK, Team.teamid, NN

**Client**
clientid, PK
clientname, NN

- PK: primary key
- FK: foreign key
- NN, not null

Many fields can be added to each table, but this structure respects your many-to-many relations, and allows you greater flexibility for your SQL queries, and future maintenance.

For Client, you did not specify what relations apply to them.  But a driver and a client are different objects.  Unless of course you want to use another level of abstraction and have a users table with types driver and client.  Unless the same person can be a client and a driver at the same time, I would not bother adding this complexity.

Comment: thank you for helping
what i understand is that team will considered as a group of drivers but in that case all drivers are equal in permission , i need one to be the owner of team (one who owns taxis and rent it) , and in case of company i need it to have many drivers and also drivers can work for many companies, so i designed it to be :
Company
companyid, PK
companyname, NN

Driver
driverid, PK
drivername, NN

Driver-Team
driverid, FK, Driver.driverid, NN
driverid, FK, Driver.driverid, NN

Company-Team
companyid, FK, Company.companyid, NN
driverid, FK, Driver.driverid, NN